# Setting default browser for activity programmatically

Tags: android, web

I'm developing an android app and among other functionality I need to open some urls in external web browser. Can I programmatically set a default application for that, so the user won't be able to choose from the list of available browsers? I mean, I want to set default browser only for my app but not for the whole operating system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, for this you can force your application to always open native android browser only. For this you have to identify the launching `Activity` of `Browser` application, something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.google.android.browser","com.google.android.browser.BrowserActivity"));
intent.setAction("android.intent.action.VIEW");
intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.BROWSABLE");
Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
intent.setData(uri);
try
{
    startActivity(intent);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: can you tell me what is `com.google.android.browser` and where comes the url ?
I am getting always null when i click to a link it open my apk for search but always null.

Comment: `com.google.android.browser` is the package name for default browser of android. Can you check if you've the native default browser available in your device?

Comment: do you know how to make an if statment which looks if `intent.getDataString()` has link or not ?

Comment: You could always check for `null`, read through the [Intent documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Comment: I just founded that I tried `isEmpty()` but leaded me to error and then tried `null` and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

You can use .setPackage for the intent: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setPackage(java.lang.String) . Call it with the browser's package name (defined in its manifest, **package** attribute).

I'm using something similar for firing up the Google+ application for sharing a string:

```
Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(getActivity())
           .setText("Dummy string to share")
           .setType("text/plain")
           .getIntent()
           .setPackage("com.google.android.apps.plus");

        startActivity(shareIntent);
```

In my example, "com.google.android.apps.plus" is the package name for the Google+ application.

Answer (score 0):

Sharedpreference for Browser class is "MODE_private" , so we can't access the home_page changing steps directly programatically,

iff we want to do, we should do through Browser.java opensource code and we should get some idea from there itself.