# Set chrome as default render engine in Android

Tags: android, google-chrome, kernel, android-4.4-kitkat, android-browser

I have a Android box (Tronsmart s89) which runs Android 4.4.2 Kitkat with custom rom from Finless version 1.6.
By standard the Tronsmart usses the old Android browser as default render engine (which I think is odd since Google stopped supporting this browser in Kitkat but ok).
I am making an Android app that needs chrome as render engine for some functions I use in an in-app-webview.
As far as I know I can't force the device of using chrome as render engine from within the app.
But does anyone if it is possible to modify the Android kernel to get the job done?

Of course I have root access.

Ty in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting default browser for activity programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12584965/setting-default-browser-for-activity-programmatically)

Comment: Looked at that post, by can't get that to work in Phonegap.
Do you know where to put it?

Anyhow, if you down voted me... That's not the answer to my question. My question was if it possible to modify Android so chrome will be my standard browser.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you need is basically a `WebView` based on Chrome, instead of WebKit or whatever that device provides.

If that's the case, check the [chromeview](https://github.com/pwnall/chromeview) library.