# Web browser application - how to intercept URL intents?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-manifest, intentfilter

I have a custom ROM and have no default browser except **WebView Browser Tester**. I have develop my own kind of web browser app(webviewclient activity) and install this in a phone. Now I want that whatever URLs when user click in a phone, my browser application will intercept and load this URL. Here is what I am using in intent_filter

```
 <intent_filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent_filter>
```

But it is not working and still `WebView` browser Tester app launch and loading links. Can someone tell me how I can set my app as a default browser App OR use any special intent which can help to launch this activity while clicking on any `URL`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding both intent filters

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:scheme="http"
                android:host="*"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="*" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to identify the launching `Activity` of `Browser` application, something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("/*Pass your browser package*/","com.google.android.browser.BrowserActivity /*And pass Browser Activity*/"));
intent.setAction("android.intent.action.VIEW");
intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.BROWSABLE");
Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
intent.setData(uri);
try
{
    startActivity(intent);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer already available on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12585136/10182897) link